# How to print a String array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

String array :

```
var name=new String('Here','Is','Wasif');

I have tried this to print it : 

for(var i=0;i< name.length;i++)
        document.write(name[i]);
```

Comment: that isn't a string array.

Comment: `new String('Here','Is','Wasif') -> new String('Here') -> "Here"`. The additional arguments to the *String constructor* are *discarded* and the result is a `String` object (not an array of strings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a string array.

Try

```
var name=['Here','Is','Wasif'];


for(var i=0;i< name.length;i++)
        document.write(name[i]);
```

Comment: I didn't think it was, and I was just going to comment! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code

```
var arr = name=['Here','Is','Wasif'];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
document.write(arr[i]);
}
```

You can try your code here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/4Sgh5/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use array join. A bit more simple that a for loop.

```
var arr = ['Here', 'Is', 'Wasif'];
document.write(arr.join(' '));
```